# Buscar un registro en mongoDB por un numero de ruc

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, búsquedas

necesito buscar un registro en mongoDb por el NUMERO_RUC mediante node.js, intente por findById y me funciona perfectamente pero quiero buscar por otro dato que no sea el id, me pueden ayudar no se en que parte es mi falla.

Metodo para obtener un registro:

```
//Obtener registros con el ruc
app.get('/personas/:ruc', function(req, res) {
    rucs.findById(req.params.ruc, function(error, persona) {
   if (error) return res.status(500).send(error);

   res.json(persona);
  });
});
```

Este es el registro en MongoDB:

```
{
"_id": "5b82eaac31e4182794de57d3",
"NUMERO_RUC": "1703467785001",
"RAZON_SOCIAL": "BASANTES JARA MARIANA DE JESUS",
"NOMBRE_COMERCIAL": "",
"ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE": "ACTIVO",
}
```

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Postman y me vota el siguiente error cuando quiero obtener el registro mediante el ruc:

```
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1703467785001\" at path 
\"_id\" for model \"rucs\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"1703467785001\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "1703467785001",
"path": "_id"
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que por el método `.findById()` estas utilizando  `mongoose`.

`.findById()` recibe como parámetro un `_id` (tipo ObjectID), por lo que si deseas buscar por otro campo puedes usar el método `.findOne()` en donde le pasas un objeto con los campos que quieres filtrar.

De todas maneras echale una mirada a la documentacion de [findById()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) y [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Ej:

```
rucs.findOne({ NUMERO_RUC: req.params.ruc }, function(error, persona) {
   if (error) return res.status(500).send(error);

   res.json(persona);
});
```